# How to flash ROM on Moto E2 XT1524

Tags: rom, motorola-moto-e

How would I flash this ROM:

```
XT1524_RETEUALL_MOTOE2(4G-LTE)_5.0.2_LXI22.50-13_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml.zip
```

From

```
https://firmware.center/firmware/Motorola/Moto%20E%20%282nd%20gen-2015%29/Stock/XT1524/XT1524_RETEUALL_MOTOE2%284G-LTE%29_5.0.2_LXI22.50-13_cid7_subsidy-DEFAULT_CFC.xml.zip
```

On A Moto E2 XT1524

Answer (score 1):

Moto factory firmware images are flashed with fastboot, not recovery, so you need to do some homework/setup first. Be aware that downgrading a Moto device, while sometimes possible, is NOT supported and can result in a bricked device. You must use a factory image that is the same or newer version than you have installed already.

** BACKUP ANY IMPORTANT DATA - EVERYTHING WILL BE LOST **
** Enable OEM Unlocking in Developer Settings **PRIOR** to starting **

Backup is self explanatory. By enabling OEM Unlocking you are giving yourself an out, if something goes really wrong you have the option of unlocking the bootloader to correct it which is not possible if this switch is not set prior to starting.

If you are using Windows, you will need to install the proper drivers (Google can help you with this, I use Linux so drivers for Android devices are not relevant). Then you will need fastboot on your computer, you can get it from Google as part of the [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) package, [Minimal ADB and Fastboot package](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790), or if using Linux it is part of most distrobution's repositories.

Next extract the ZIP you linked above to your fastboot directory and shut down your phone. Startup your phone while holding the VOL DOWN button, you should get to the bootloader screen (if not, try again), then connect the USB cable and open a terminal or command window and enter the command:

`fastboot devices`

If you get a response similar to "List of devices: *SomeLongString* fastboot" you are ready to begin the flashing process. Enter each command individually ONE AT A TIME and verify each step results in a result of "Okay", if any step fails repeat it up to 2 additional times (modems frequently do not take the first time)

`fastboot oem fb_mode_set`
`fastboot flash partition gpt.bin`
`fastboot flash logo logo.bin`
`fastboot flash boot boot.img`
`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4`
`fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5`
`fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin`
`fastboot erase modemst1`
`fastboot erase modemst2`
`fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn`
`fastboot erase carrier`
`fastboot erase cache`
`fastboot erase userdata`
`fastboot oem fb_mode_clear`
`fastboot reboot`

(Every recent Moto Android device uses this same process, it is derived from the contents of flashfile.xml that is contained within the factory firmware image itself and used by Moto's factory flashing tool)

The first boot may take a significant amount of time, 10-20 minutes even, just let it work and do not interrupt it.

Be aware that there additional resources for this on XDA in their [Moto E 2015 General Discussion](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/general) area, including threads specifically for firmware images and flashing instructions.